# Type function Type List, M if then statement

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",
each if Text.Middle("IgnitionCapability",-1,1) <> ")"
then Text.Combine("IgnitionCapability",")")
else "IgnitionCapability")
```

I need help debugging this makeshift code, currently the error I am getting is:

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Function to type List.
> Details:
> Value=[Function]
> Type=[Type]

However, I'd believe there are more errors in this as I'm no sort of programmer, this is what I compiled after many internet searches.
For clarification, "IgnitionCapability" is a column. I would also appreicate it if someone would help me understand what is the type function that should've been a list for future reference.

Comment: The `Transform Operations` are supposed to be a **List**.  In your code, you have it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the original question posted previously, comparing string by index number

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(
    Json.Document(
      Binary.Decompress(
        Binary.FromText("i45Wcs7PLUgsSlXSUfLNTy5ITSxSio0FAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), 
        Compression.Deflate
      )
    ), 
    let
      _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
    in
      type table [Text1 = _t, Text2 = _t]
  ), 
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Text1", type text}, {"Text2", type text}}), 
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Changed Type", 
    "Custom.2", 
    each if Text.ToList([Text1]){0} = Text.ToList([Text2]){0} then "match" else "non-match"
  )
in
  #"Added Custom"
```

You edit the code to modify string index# here inside curly bracket
`Text.ToList([Text1]){0} = Text.ToList([Text2]){0}`

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my comment, you are using a function for the **Transform Operation** argument of `Table.TransformColumns` where it should be a list.

As you surmise, there are multiple other errors in your code as well, and you should probably correct them one at a time to better figure it out.  But you are also using an invalid offset argument in Text.Middle, and using strings instead of references for your arguments in the transform operation itself.

You don't really describe what you are trying to do.  If what you want to do is add a `")"` onto the end of strings in the designated column that don't have them, one way to do that would be:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",
        {"IgnitionCapability",
        each  if not Text.EndsWith(_,")") then _ & ")" else _, type text})
```

*Note also that I added the column type argument to your transform operation*